# How does one intercept nested_attributes for further processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

tl;dr: Is it possible to intercept posted values from a nested model for further processing? I've tried everything I can think of to access the nested attributes to use for a `before_save` callback, but that may be only a testament to the limits of my imagination.

I'm writing a library application, where books can have many authors and vice versa. That bit is working just fine with a `has_many_through` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. The app saves all the book and author information just fine. Except... I can't seem to write a working `before_save` on either the Author or Book model to check if the Author that we're trying to create exists. Here's what I already have:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :authorships
has_many :authors, :through => :authorships
accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors, :authorships
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :authorships
has_many :books, :through => :authorships
before_save :determine_distinct_author


def determine_distinct_author
  Author.find_or_create_by_author_last( @author )
end
end

## books_controller.rb ##
def new
  @book = Book.new
  @book.authors.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml  { render :xml => @book }
  end
end

def create
  @book = Book.new(params[:book])
  @author = @book.authors #I know this line is wrong. This is the problem (I think.)

# more here, obviously, but nothing out of ordinary
end
```

When I post the form, the dev log passes on this:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Book",\
"authenticity_token"=>"/K4/xATm7eGq/fOmrQHKyYQSKxL9zlVM8aqZrSbLNC4=",\
"utf8"=>"✓", "book"{"title"=>"Test", "ISBN"=>"", "genre_id"=>"1", "notes"=>"", \
"authors_attributes"=>{"0"{"author_last"=>"McKinney", "author_first"=>"Jack"}}, \
"publisher"=>"", "pages"=>"", "language_id"=>"1", "location_id"=>"1"}}
```

So... the data's there. But how do I get to it to process it? When I post the data, here's that log:

```
Author Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `authors`.* FROM `authors` WHERE\
`authors`.`author_last` IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

I've done a fair bit of searching around to see what there is out there on nested attributes, and I see a lot on the form side, but not much on how to get to the assets once they're submitted.

Any explanation of why the solution which works does actually work would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The nested attributes is an array, and should be accessed as an array. Getting the submission from the one model to the next still presents quite a problem.

2) `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is probably not going to help out a whole lot, and there will undoubtedly be a lot of custom processing which will have to happen between now and when the whole system is fully functional. Probably best to ditch it now and move on.

In that direction: It looks like [Ryan Bates has done a recent bit](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) on the jQuery TokenInput plugin which will take care of a lot of the autocomplete feature on the author. More to the larger problem (and a bit harder to find), is a [follow up](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/11#issuecomment-904344) that he posted to some issues with the plugin on working with new entries.

Comment: Direct link to the jquery plugin: [here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) for those who'd like to skip directly there.

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works, yet I do not completely agree with your assesment about `accepts_nested_attributes`: normally your form should build it correctly so you would not need to handle it inside your controller at all: just save it. Nevertheless the plugin looks nice, and I will investigate that :)

Answer (score 1):

First, this line

```
@author = @book.authors
```

assigns an array of authors to @author, but in your before_save you seem to be expecting a single author model. Secondly, the @author variable is scoped to the controller and will be empty in your model's scope.

Remove that line and try this in your Book class (not tested):

```
def determine_distinct_author
  authors.each do |author|
      Author.find_or_create_by_author_last( author )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but inside your `Author` you have a `before_save` callback, and that is obviously giving the error.

To me it seems you are looking for an author with the given name, and then want to use that? Is that correct?

Using a nested form, you will always create a new author, unless you want to use something like a select-box, and then select an author-id (which is part of the book, so not nested), instead of the authors details.

UX-wise, i would offer the option to either select an existing author (use an autocomplete field), or create a new one (using the nested fields option --without your `before_save` callback).

Comment: Interesting. I've edited the original question to reflect some of what you bring up. The original idea was a select box, but with 600+ authors, that's not going to work. It will eventually be a "typedown" type interface, but I figured that was step 5, and I'm still on step 1 (or 0, perhaps).